# In angularjs, What is the different between those 2 controllers

Tags: angularjs

I've seen 2 types of controllers definition:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope'], function($scope){
   //controller code
}
```

And a simple:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  //controller code
}
```

What's the different? Which one is the preferred one?

Comment: The same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362921/globally-defined-angularjs-controllers-and-encapsulation/13363482#13363482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first is a controller inside the module. 
The second method is a controller on the global ( on the Window object! ).

Like you would have heard already, polluting the global object is a bad idea. Hence, the second method is not preferred (But is used for quick prototyping to show off a feature easily and is easier to type. So this one is used in pretty much all examples.)

The first way, i.e

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope'], function($scope){
   //controller code
}
```

is the preferred way and should be used in all for production applications.