# AngularJS - different ways to create controllers and services, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep seeing different examples of creating controllers and services in AngularJS and I'm confused, can anyone explain to me the differences between the two approaches?

```
app.service('reverseService', function() {
    this.reverse = function(name) {
        return name.split("").reverse().join("");
    };
});

app.factory('reverseService', function() {
    return {
        reverse : function(name) {
            return name.split("").reverse().join("");
        }
    }
});
```

And also a controller example:

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = "some data";
}

app.controller("ExampleCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = "some data";
}
```

Comment: A question very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13362921/1418796

Comment: I couldn't find the answer, that's why I raised my own question, given the title of that question and my question, I believe my question should stand to aid others.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first one will pollute the [global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted), which is not what you want in the long run.

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope){
    $scope.data = "some data";
}
```

The second one scopes the Controller to that module instance. It makes it also [injectable](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Better still is using the array notation (as below), since this will survive minification.

```
app.controller("ExampleCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.data = "some data";
}]);
```

The difference between an (angular) service and factory seems quite small. A service wraps a factory, which uses [$injector.instantiate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$injector#instantiate) to initialize the service.

Comment: How can you add Factories on the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of creating controllers and directives is as following:

```
/**
* SomeCoolModule.controller.js
*/

(function(){
'use strict';

    angular.module('app.modals.SomeCoolModule').controller('SomeCoolModuleController', SomeCoolModuleController);

    AddFlowCurveModalController.$inject =
        [
            '$scope',
            '$filter',
            '$log',
        ];

    function SomeCoolModuleController($scope, $filter, $log) {
        /* controller body goes here */
    }
})();
```

PS: no global namespace pollution is taking place above due to IIFE.

Comment: I do the same with services also :)