# Add more locals in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Here is a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14184707/1447885) of constructing a controller. What if I need to add the `$location` in my controller?

e.g.

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope,$location){
    $scope.data = "some data";
    $location.path('/');
}
```

How should the array notation look like?

Comment: You mean `app.controller("ExampleCtrl", ['$scope','$location', function($scope , $location){
    $scope.data = "some data";
}]);` ?

Comment: @Cherniv your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @dusan True. Add it as answer Cherniv and I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
app.controller("ExampleCtrl", ['$scope','$location', function($scope , $location){
     $scope.data = "some data"; 
}]);
```