# $routeParams gets undefined in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I am making a call an http call to a json file. In the first controller I get the categories , and in the second controller I get the category with a certain ID.

The url gets updated with an categoryid but the $routeParams is shown undefined and cannnot access the file.

Here is my code:

```
$stateProvider.state('categories', {
  url: '/category',
  templateUrl: 'templates/categories.html',
  controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
});
$stateProvider.state('postC', {
  url: '/category/:category',
  templateUrl: 'templates/postsc.html',
  controller: 'PostCtrl'
});
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
angular.module('myapp')

.controller('CategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("~/wp/v2/terms/category")
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.categories = res.data;
      })
  }
])

.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get("~/wp/v2/terms/category/" + $routeParams.category).success(function(res) {

      $scope.current_category_id = $routeParams.category;
      console.log($routeParams.category);
      $scope.pageTitle = 'Posts in ' + res.data.name + ':';
      document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = 'Category: ' + res.data.name + ' | AngularJS Demo Theme';

      $http.get("~/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=" + res.data.name).success(function(res) {
        $scope.posts = res.data;
        console.log($scope.posts);
      })

    })
  }
]);
```

The view for the categories is the following:

```
<div class="list">
  <a ng-repeat="category in categories" href="#/category/{{category.id}}" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
    <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

And when I click on the category the URL becomes: http://localhost:8100/#/category/12,  but the $stateparams.category in `~/wp/v2/terms/category/" + $routeParams.category` is undefined therefor the http request cannot go through.

I cannot figure it out what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `$routeParams` with `$stateParams` in every instance. You're obviously using `ui-router` which uses "states", while `ngRouter` uses "routes".

```
angular.module('myapp')

.controller('CategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("~/wp/v2/terms/category")
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.categories = res.data;
      })
  }
])

.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams',
  function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
    $http.get("~/wp/v2/terms/category/" + $stateParams.category).success(function(res) {

      $scope.current_category_id = $stateParams.category;
      console.log($stateParams.category);
      $scope.pageTitle = 'Posts in ' + res.data.name + ':';
      document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = 'Category: ' + res.data.name + ' | AngularJS Demo Theme';

      $http.get("~/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=" + res.data.name).success(function(res) {
        $scope.posts = res.data;
        console.log($scope.posts);
      })

    })
  }
]);
```

Comment: so instead of $stateParams I write $routeParams.. I will try now

Comment: And also try `console.log($stateParams);` before `$http.get...` to see everything before GET happens, just FYI.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You might want to double-check the code near

```
.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $routeParams)
```

it should be

```
.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams)
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184656/angularjs-different-ways-to-create-controllers-and-services-why) on syntax of creating a Controller. You are missing injectors.

Comment: Ops yes that was a type. I fixed it but still I have the same prb

Comment: Are you able to console.log the $routeParams variable? Besides, which one is undefined: $routeParams.category or $routeParams.categoryId?

Comment: $routeParams.category is undefined (ignore the categoryid).I consolelog it but it is undefined

Comment: Its incorrect answer..'ui.router' doesn;t give information in `$routeParams` object..

Comment: @PankajParkar - yeah, the code snippest has plenty of coding error. I have just correct one of them. Though it was very important, too.